# what are meta-models in CDS views?

Tags: abap

while understanding CDS views,I've come across something like '**meta-model**' could anyone please explain me what does it mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not an official term.

Guess you're refering to its usage in the article [*ABAP Core Data Services – Introduction (ABAP CDS view)*](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/09/abap-core-data-services-introduction-abap-cds-view/)?

The article uses the term "meta model" to refer to annotations in CDS views. Annotations describe the meaning, application, and properties of entities, fields, and associations in CDS views.

For example, an annotation might say that an association joins a text for a code field or that a field should be used for fuzzy search.

While the select and calculations in the CDS view tell you how to produce the actual data (= the model), the annotations tell you how to interpret that data (= the meta model).